# Set a module to try to serve content over https instead of http

Tags: module, magento-1, secure

This part of the ogone plugin gives a person insight into his/her order history.

Problem is, this thingymijig redirects to http protocol instead of https. Other nasty sideeffect is that it redirects to main store if it's not over https.

How do I change it that it generates the url in user account information as a magento secure url instead of a magento base url?

Stupid plugin developper won't fix this within a reasonable time, so I started to fix this myself, but the snag I'm running into is that I cannot find any documentation of how to set a module page to run over https/generate links that go via the secure base url.

Anyone know any documentation about setting modules to https or how to fix this?

**app/design/frontend/base/store/layout/ops.xml**

```
<customer_account>
        <reference name="customer_account_navigation">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="ops"><name>ops_payment_information</name><path>ops/customer/aliases</path><label>My payment information</label></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
    </customer_account>
    <ops_customer_aliases translate="label">
        <label>My payment information</label>
        <update handle="customer_account"/>
        <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
            <block type="ops/alias_list" name="ops_customer_aliases" template="ops/customer/alias/list.phtml" />
        </reference>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setHeaderTitle" translate="title" module="ops"><title>My payment information</title></action>
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/3columns.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
    </ops_customer_aliases>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the `secure_url` node under `frontend` in the config.xml of the extension to force the use of the secure-url. Below the snippet used in the config.xml for the Mage_Sales:

```
   <frontend>
        <secure_url>
            <sales>/sales/</sales>
        </secure_url>
```

Comment: Ha, great! that works too, but I just now found out that when having an **action** tag it doesn't work like that.
http://www.matthias-zeis.com/archiv/magento-top-links-anpassen
This is what you need to edit in an action tag.
`<urlParams><_secure>true</_secure></urlParams>`
Thank you anyways, now there is an english answer too on google ;-)